# How can i edit my ingredients through array of input fields

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

How can I make a form like posting my ingredient but in the way that I will only edit the posted ingredients

this is the Javascript of the button

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields = 25; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) { //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-6 div-' + x + '"><input                     type="text" class="form-control" name="mytext[]" required/></div>'); //add input box
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="col-md-6 div-' + x + '"><input type="text" class="form-control" name="mytext2[]" required/><a href="#" class="remove_field" div-id="' + x + '">Remove</a></div>');

    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) { //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".div-" + $(this).attr("div-id")).remove();
    x--;
  })
});
</script>
```

This is the form of inserting the ingredients

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h5>Notes/Scaling (quantity, additional info)</h5>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mytext2[]" required>
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <h5>Name of Ingredient:</h5>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="mytext[]" required>
    <br>
  </div>
  <br>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
  <button class="add_field_button button loading-pulse">Add More Fields</button>
</div>
```

this is how i implode it

```
        $ingredient_name =implode("^",$_POST["mytext"]);
        $ingredient_value = implode("^", $_POST["mytext2"]);
```

this is how i explode it

```
$ingredient_name = explode("^",$ingredient_name);
$ingredient_value = explode("^", $ingredient_scale);
$ingredients = array_combine($ingredient_value,$ingredient_name);
```

this is how i loop it

```
                                    <table class="table-bordered" style="width:90%;">

                                            <th style="text-align:center;">Ingredient Scale</th>
                                            <th style="text-align:center;">Ingredient Name</th>
                                            <?php 
                                            foreach($ingredients as $amount => $name)
                                            {

                                                ?>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td style="margin:left:10px;"><?php echo "{$amount}"?></td>
                                                <td  style="margin:left:10px;"><?php echo "{$name}"?></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <?php 
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                    </table>
```

for example in the database
there are 2 columns,

### recipe_ingredient_value recipe_ingredient_name

- 1/4,1/2,1 cup                          sugar,meat,water

i want it to extract into an input fields that i can edit (rename, add ,delete)
for example

- 1/4                   sugar            remove
- 1/2                   meat             remove
- 1 cup                 water            remove

add more fields

Comment: I don't get what you want. Can you show an example of the end goal?

Comment: for example in the database
there are 2 columns, 
recipe_ingredient_value         recipe_ingredient_name
1/4,1/2,1 cup                          sugar,meat,water

i want it to extract into an input fields that i can edit (rename, add ,delete)
for example 
1/4                   sugar            remove
1/2                   meat             remove
1 cup               water            remove 

add more fields

Comment: remember to set one of the answered as the correct answer if it solved your issue. If not then you can comment more questions in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should print all values in a form inside the loop and then you need some sort of "Save" button and a route ready to receive new values. This route should be a php script, for example, that would loop through your new data and perform an update.

I'm suggesting you're writing PHP framework-free, standalone app. That way you have to think about a lot of things, which is good for you if you are a beginner.

Now back to the point:

It would be great if you could print a hidden id of a database row, somewhere inside the loop:

```
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="recipe_id" value="<?php echo $amount; ?> /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="recipe_id" value="<?php echo $name; ?> /></td>
<input type="hidden" name="recipe_id" value="<?php echo $recipe_id; ?> />
</tr>
```

Remember that route that collects and updates the data? Let's call it "update-script.php".
The update-script.php should perform a check for every field in a $_GET or $_POST variable, to see if that value has been changed. If yes, the row should be updated, if not, then it should be skipped. It's up to you to create the logic for this.

Furthermore, I noticed that your javascript code needs some adjustments. I will only hint one thing that kinda sticks out:

```
$(add_button).click(function(e){
```

For the sake of your future work, please use "on" method that is described here:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Trust me, when you start working with DOM elements, changing the DOM and adding new events, this will be your savior.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to structure your inputs like this.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="recipe[<?= $recipe_id; ?>][id]" value="<?php echo $recipe_id; ?>"  placeholder="value"/>
        <input type="text" name="recipe[<?= $recipe_id; ?>][value]" value="<?php echo $value; ?>"  placeholder="name"/>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="recipe[<?= $recipe_id; ?>][name]" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></td>
    <td><input id="recipe_<?= $recipe_id; ?>" type="checkbox" name="recipe[<?= $recipe_id; ?>][delete]" value="1" /><label for="recipe_?= $recipe_id; ?>">Delete</label></td>
</tr>
```

Where $recipe id is the row id. Then your javascript would add more rows like

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="recipe[2][value]" value="" placeholder="value" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="recipe[2][name]" value="" placeholder="name" /></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Then in your php you can see the array will be formatted nicely into arrays of recipes like:

```
array(
    array(
        'name' => 'Pie'
        'value' => 2
        'recipe_id' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'Deleted Pie'
        'value' => 2
        'recipe_id' => 2
        'deleted' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'New pie'
        'value' => 2
    ),
)
```

Then using the deleted key you can check if you need to delete the Database row and if it has the recipe_id key then it might need to be updated. If it doesn't have the recipe key then its a new recipe.